# Nested containers of different types

Tags: c++, stl

I am new to STL and wanted to know the best way to implement this:
I wanted to nest containers with elements of different types. My idea was a set, whose elements could be either vectors or maps.

This way I could iterate through the set applying common operations to all its elements. At the same time, some of the operations on the elements, would be dependant on the vector or map type. However, I assume that all the elements must be of the same type.

Would there be an alternative to implement something like this?

Comment: So you want a `std::set<boost::variant<std::vector, std::map>>`?

Comment: Doesn't really make sense. A set is ordered, which means you have to order vectors relative to maps.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put two different kinds of objects into a standard container. What you have to do is "wrap" the container in another object that "knows" what kind of object it is actually holding. `boost::variant<T1, T2 ... >` is a relatively standard way of doing it. If you can't use the boost library, then you may find something like this works OK:

```
struct wrapper
{
     int type;  // or enum 
     union {
         vector v;
         map m;
     } content;
};
```

Comment: Note the approach in the code is only valid in C++11, and you would have to provide some extra code to the `wrapper` to make it work (in particular setting the union to refer to one type or the other requires calling the appropriate constructor/destructor as to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for the boost::variant suggestion. I think I am going to first try a boost-less approach with single nested type, then later dive into boost.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not really supported by the language, and while you can make it work, it won't be simple or elegant. The approach suggested by sftrabbit (once you fix the syntax :)) can get you half way there, but the iteration will require the creation of a visitor, probably taking a functor to be applied to the elements; to be able to use it inside an ordered container you will need to wrap it in a type that provides the ordering...

Another issue with your intended design is that `std::set` does not allow the modification of the nested elements, which basically means that once you add the containers into the `std::set` they become immutable. If that is fine, you can take a different approach and just maintain a `std::vector<ElementType*>` to point to all of the existing elements *after* inclusion into the outer `std::set`. That will let you iterate on a much simpler linear fashion over all of the elements.

A simpler solution could be creating a class that replaces the outer container and internally holds two different `std::set` (again assuming that the immutability is not an issue, or a different container if needed) one for each nested container:

```
class Container {
   std::set<std::vector<Type>> d_vectors;
   std::set<std::map<Key,Type>> d_maps;
...
```

Then the `Container` type can contain the functions that iterate over the internal containers.

Then again, you might want to revisit the original problem and find out that there are simpler approaches that don't need this in the first place... and are probably cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think you understood my problem better than I explained it.
Since my small project's main objective is learning, I am going to first revisit the problem and use a single nested type.
Afterwards, I will probably try the boost::variant approach.